# How to make a StackPanel Width that of another StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, width, stackpanel, dockpanel

I have two dockpanels which each have a left StackPanel.

The width of the **bottom** StackPanel is determined by the width of the **text** is in it.

The width of the **top** StackPanel should be the **same** as the width of the **bottom** StackPanel.

I've tried to bind the Width of the top StackPanel to the Width of the bottom StackPanel via ElementName but this doesn't work.

**How can I make the top width the same as the bottom width?**

[image]

```
<StackPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="100" >
        <StackPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=LeftMenuText, Path=Width}" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock
                Text="This is some text."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Background="Orange">
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel 
        Height="3"
        Background="Black"></DockPanel>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="100">
        <StackPanel Name="LeftMenuWrapper"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock 
                    Text="This is some text that is longer."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Background="Blue">
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind it to ActualWidth of LeftMenuWrapper:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="100" >
        <StackPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=LeftMenuWrapper, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock
                Text="This is some text."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Background="Orange">
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel 
        Height="3"
        Background="Black"></DockPanel>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="100">
        <StackPanel Name="LeftMenuWrapper"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock 
                    Text="This is some text that is longer."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Background="Blue">
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Just to add to your arsenal another way to do this. You can also use Grid's IsSharedScope property:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
      <Grid Height="100">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TextHolder"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Border Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock Text="This is some text."/>
         </Border>
         <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Orange"/>
      </Grid>
      <Border Height="3" Background="Black"/>
      <Grid Height="100">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="TextHolder"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Border Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock Text="This is some text that is longer."/>
         </Border>
         <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue"/>
      </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `Grid`s with a `SharedSizeGroup` instead of `DockPanel`s. I.e.

```
<StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid Height="100" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=LeftMenuText, Path=Width}"
                                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock
                    Text="This is some text."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Background="Orange">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <DockPanel
      Height="3"
      Background="Black"></DockPanel>

    <Grid Height="100">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Name="LeftMenuWrapper"
                                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock
                            Text="This is some text that is longer."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Background="Blue">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The key things to remember are to give each column inside your grids a `SharedSizeGroup` with the same name ("A" in this example), and add `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` to a shared parent of the `Grid`s (the `StackPanel` containing the `Grid`s in this example)